# Why changing editor font in codeblocks 20.03 is showing wxWidgets debug alert?

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets

I have recently installed 20.03 version of codeblocks, but when I tried to change the editor font it showed me a debug alert like this:

[image: wxWidgets debug alert ,A debugging check in this aplication has failed.]

Two option arises there, stop and continue. If I click stop, it stops the application, and by clicking continue it keeps showing the alert message. If I restart the app it keeps showing again and again.
if anyone can help me, please do help.

Comment: are you trying to use some non-default font? The one that is not installed on the system?

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same issue. After toggling a bit, I found this warning is showing when I try to change the font size and style of the editor. You can get rid of the issue by following few steps and also set the font style and size according to your choice.

1. Open the Codeblocks. If the warning shows, just hit the continue button for now.
2. Go to settings then editor from the editor.
   [image: Screenshot 1]
3. Choose your desired font and size.
   [image: Screenshot 2]

In my case, I have selected font Cambria and size 14.
Copy the font name by pressing ctrl+c.

4. Now press ok. Here you might get that warning again. Just click continue for now.
5. Close the Codeblocks.
6. Go to C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\CodeBlocks\default.conf press ctrl+f and type 'font'. It may look something the like this:

   ```
    <FONT>
        <str>
            <![CDATA[1;14.8;-23;0;0;0;400;0;0;0;0;3;2;1;18;Arial]]>
        </str>
    </FONT>
   ```
7. Here the second number represents the font size (14.8) and the "Arial" text is the font name. Change 14.8 according to selected font size you chose in the editor and paste the font name in place of "Arial". For me it looked like:

   ```
    <FONT>
        <str>
            <![CDATA[1;14;-23;0;0;0;400;0;0;0;0;3;2;1;18;Cambria]]>
        </str>
    </FONT>
   ```
8. Don't forget to save it, now close it. Reopen the codeblocks and whole! there is no more warning.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the exact same problem, and using the older version of Code::Blocks resolved the issue.

Maybe something's a bit wrong with the latest version of C::B?

Comment: okay,that might be the issue.I had previously used an older version of C::B and there was no problem .May be you are right.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a checkbox "Don't show again in the dialog", which can be used to prevent the message box from being shown again if you press "Continue".

Second, you should report this as a bug to C::B developers, with the instructions about how to reproduce it (notably which font you chose), as it looks like an invalid font is somehow being created. It's also rather strange that they don't disable debug alerts in the production version of C::B, so you might ask them to do this too.

Answer (score 0):

edit this file `..\AppData\Roaming\CodeBlocks\default.conf`
ctrl+f find `font`

```
<FONT>
            <str>
                <![CDATA[1;14.5;-23;0;0;0;400;0;0;0;0;3;2;1;49;Consolas]]>
            </str>
        </FONT>
```

change the number `14.5` to any int or float like `*.5`  `*.25` `*.75`

got this from [here](https://my.oschina.net/wwfifi/blog/4282989)

Comment: There isn't any `<FONT>` tag in the `default.conf` file. If I create one, C::B v20.03 automatically removes it.

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the default font, there should be a something similar to:

```
<FONT>
    <str>
        <![CDATA[1;10.8;-18;0;0;0;400;0;0;0;0;10;2;1;49;FiraCode NF]]>
    </str>
</FONT>
```

in the file `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\CodeBlocks\default.conf`. For some reason, replacing the second number, in this case 10.8, with an integer, e.g. 11, "solved" the issue for me (at least I don't see the warning anymore).

Answer (score 0):

If you go into Settings -> Editor and change the font size to 9 or 15, that seems to fix it with the couple of fonts I've tried.