# wxWidgets font error in Code::Blocks "assert "numWeight > 0" failed in GetWeightClosestToNumericValue()"

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets

I've been recently suffering from a error dialog keep popping up whenever I use Code::Blocks.

It says "A debugging error in this application has failed." and "....\include/wx/font.h(282): assert "numWeight > 0" failed in GetWeightClosestToNumericValue()."

This thing has been popping up since I tried to change my fonts in Code::Blocks, and since then whenever I change my font to something else, it always get reset.

The dialog pops up when I start up the Code::Blocks, when I open a source code in Code::Blocks, and when I open Settings-Editor in Code::Blocks.

I've looked up for similar cases around, and they said it's a problem with wxWidgets, but still I couldn't find any solution that can fix this problem.

I also tried enabling "Reset zoom of all editors to defaults, if leaving dialog", and it didn't work either.

(Also tried removing and reinstalling Code::Blocks, and the issue still exists)

If anyone could help me resolving this problem, I would be truly grateful.

[image]

Comment: Seems to be very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63439581/why-changing-edior-font-in-codeblocks-20-03-is-showing-wxwidgets-debug-alert/63449342

Answer (score 9):

if you customize the theme of CodeBlocks, it may occur that problem!
so..let's solve it...
you can have a try with simple methode:

select "Setting"->"Editor"，then click "General Setting" section,choose "Font" and choose "Size":12 or 18,Don't choose 14 or 16...

..Amazing, it works...

Answer (score 3):

As the user tguichaoua hints to, erasing your config file will help.

It is located in `%APPDATA%\CodeBlocks\default.conf` (this might vary if you're using the portable version).

For me opening it and finding the `FONT` tag (`<FONT>...</FONT>`) and deleting it was enough to reset the editor font and fix the constant errors.

Also [apparently](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=23962.0) this is fixed in the newer versions of CodeBlocks (since at least June 2020) so you might want to change to a [nightly version](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/board,20.0.html) instead. I have had no such issues with fonts using the latest nightly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure if this is an ultimate solution, but it seems like the older versions of Code::Blocks do not have such issues.

I uninstalled the current version (20.03) and installed previous version (17.12) and it's working just fine!

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem by deleting all files in `...\AppData\Roaming\CodeBlocks` and restart Code::Block.